# Restrict Compare Products for Guest

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php-7.2

> **I want to restrict compare products for guest when guest compare 3 products.**

**How can i do that ?**

I tried the following code but not worked for guest. It is working for registered users only.

In My di.xml file

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add">
        <plugin name="LimitToCompareProducts"
                type="Vendor\Catalog\Model\Plugin\Compare\LimitToCompareProducts"/>
    </type>
```

In My modal file

```
if($count >= 3) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
            'You can add the compared products under 3 item(s)'
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerSession = $session;
    ...
}
```

> **You need to count guest user comapre product count here**

```
if(($count >= 3) && (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()))
{
    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('You can add the compared products under 3 item(s)');
}
```

**I Hope This Helps You.**

Comment: For guests there is no limit the add to compare products I have added 5 products . it is not showing error message

Comment: But you have to count guest Compare products.